# Combine XML elements with xsl

Tags: xslt

I have the following xml:

```
<RowSet>
  <Row>
    <Number>12345</Number>
    <Quantity>42</Quantity>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Number>12345</Number>
    <Quantity>12</Quantity>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Number>54321</Number>
    <Quantity>37</Quantity>
  </Row>
</RowSet>
```

I want to use an xsl to combine the elements with the same Number and the resulting should sum the Quantity elements.  So the output should look like this:

```
<RowSet>
  <Row>
    <Number>12345</Number>
    <Quantity>64</Quantity>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Number>54321</Number>
    <Quantity>37</Quantity>
  </Row>
</RowSet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<xsl:key name="kRow" match="Row" use="Number" />

<xsl:template match="RowSet">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Row[
      generate-id() = generate-id(key('kRow', Number)[1])
    ]" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Row">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="Number" />
    <Quantity>
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kRow', Number)/Quantity)" />
    </Quantity>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is close but the RowSet was removed and I ended up with two Number elements that were identical.  Here's the resulting XML:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Row>
  <Number>20000689</Number>
  <Quantity>28132</Quantity>
</Row>
<Row>
  <Number>20000689</Number>
  <Quantity>28132</Quantity>
</Row>
<Row>
  <Number>10000294</Number>
  <Quantity>1502.778</Quantity>
</Row>

Comment: @mpenrow: Very probably because you are making a mistake. My code is fine, according to your sample.

Comment: Thanks for checking.  I am a noob at this xsl stuff so it is entirely possible I am making a mistake.

Comment: @mpenrow: Check XML Namespaces, compare case (XML is case sensitive), and also structural differences. You can't be very far.